# react-native-contacts returns undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm tryna get the contacts list of the device but react-native-contacts returns undefined.

[image]

I've Installed the package and linked it as mentioned in the project's GitHub page 
https://github.com/rt2zz/react-native-contacts

I've also added the permissions to the android-manifest file.
How do I get it works

Comment: put your code here. I think problem is in your app.js file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens mostly because of the linking-step was missing as there are native modules required:

After `npm install react-native-contacts` (or `yarn add`) you are required to link the stuff with

`react-native link react-native-contacts`

Afterwards you need to **rebuild** your project (`react-native run-android` or build in Android Studio). Just to "Reload" in Simulator or on Device is not sufficient after linking a native library.

Also some more permissions needs to be placed in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My stack :

- react-native: 0.45.1
- react-native-contacts: ^1.0.0"

I was still getting the error after linking the module as specified above. Finally resolved the issue after adding the following to `ReactNativeContacts.java` (`/node_modules/react-native-contacts/android/src/main/java/com/rt2zz/reactnativecontacts`):

```
import com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaScriptModule;

@override public List<Class<? extends JavaScriptModule>> createJSModules() { return Collections.emptyList(); }
```